# Wrap Akka Streams Source & Sink with a token refresh mechanism

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Let's assume we have an Akka Streams based API (`Api` in the example below) which allows us to upload & download data, but only if a valid token is provided. There is also a function to refresh the token in case it is expired. However, tokens should only be refreshed if expired, it is not OK to refresh it prior to every invocation.

I'd like to wrap this `Api` into a higher level API (`WithRefreshes` in the example below) which would handle the token refreshes automatically, while presenting largely the same API to the clients (just without taking the `token` parameter in calls).

This means providing an implementation of `WithRefreshesImpl` in the code below so that `TestSpec` passes.

The constraints are that this should be idiomatic Scala and Akka Streams code - so no blocking `Await.result`-s and ideally we'd like to leave it to the `Api` implementation to consume the `String`-s in case of `Sink` or to the client to retrieve them in case of the `Source`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object TestProtocol {
  case class Token(value: String) extends AnyVal
  type Result = Future[Boolean]
}

import TestProtocol._

trait WithRefreshes {
  def sinkWithRefresh(): Sink[String, Result]
  def sourceWithRefresh(): Source[String, Result]
}

// code to fix / implement starts 
class WithRefreshesImpl(api: Api) extends WithRefreshes {
  var token: Token = Await.result(api.refreshToken(), Duration.Inf) // TODO: we want to cache tokens to avoid refreshing them again and again

  override def sinkWithRefresh(): Sink[String, Result] = {
    api.sink(token) // TODO: we want to refresh tokens when needed
  }

  override def sourceWithRefresh(): Source[String, Result] = {
    api.source(token) // TODO: we want to refresh tokens when needed
  }
}
// code to fix / implement ends

trait Api {
  def sink(token: Token): Sink[String, Result]
  def source(token: Token): Source[String, Result]
  def refreshToken(): Future[Token]
}

class MockApi(data: String) extends Api {
  private val expiredToken = Token("expired")
  private val successfulToken = Token("ok")
  private val failedToken = Token("failed")

  private val refreshTokenCount = new AtomicInteger()

  override def sink(token: Token): Sink[String, Result] = {
    Sink.ignore.mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.successful(token == successfulToken))
  }

  override def source(token: Token): Source[String, Result] = {
    if (token == successfulToken) {
      Source.single(data).mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.successful(true))
    } else {
      Source.empty[String].mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.successful(false))
    }
  }

  /** Returning expired token on first invocation, then a successful token on the second one, then failed tokens for subsequent invocations*/
  override def refreshToken(): Future[Token] = {
    val result = refreshTokenCount.getAndIncrement() match {
      case 0 => expiredToken
      case 1 => successfulToken
      case _ => failedToken
    }

    Future.successful(result)
  }
}

import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures._
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

class TestSpec extends FlatSpec {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val data = "data"

  it should "work for uploads" in {
    val mockApi = new MockApi(data)
    val withRefreshes = new WithRefreshesImpl(mockApi)
    val sink = withRefreshes.sinkWithRefresh()
    val result = Source.single("test").runWith(sink)
    whenReady(result) { _ shouldEqual true }
  }

  it should "work for downloads" in {
    val mockApi = new MockApi(data)
    val withRefreshes = new WithRefreshesImpl(mockApi)
    val source = withRefreshes.sourceWithRefresh()
    val (result, dataF) = source.toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.both).run
    whenReady(result) { _ shouldEqual true }
    whenReady(dataF) { _ shouldEqual data }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know if a token has expired?

Comment: The `Result` returned by the `Api` trait methods `sink` and `source` will be `false`. `MockApi` has what I think is a primitive implementation.

Comment: To understand the background, a real implementation of the `Api` trait would invoke an HTTP service using Akka HTTP and that service would return a HTTP 401 error with a "token_expired" error code, but this would get processed by the `Api` implementation to just return a `false` `Result`.

Comment: Why isn't there a `def stillValid(token : Token) : Boolean` method to test if a token is still good?  Perhaps I'm not understanding the design but putting this functionality in the `source` or `sink` doesn't make sense

Comment: Because this wraps a real-world API that I have no control over and there is no `def stillValid(token: Token)` call in it. All it can do is say that the token is expired when trying to upload/download.

Why doesn't it make sense to put this functionality in the `source` or `sink`?

Comment: So the only way to determine that a token is expired is to send it to the sink, and if the sink materializes into a `Result` of `false` then the Token needs to be refreshed?

Comment: And why is sink part of the trait?  Shouldn't the API from the third party give you that?  Especially given that specific type signature...

Comment: The API from the third party is an HTTP API. 

The only way to tell if the token is expired is to try the HTTP request and see if the "invalid_token" error is returned or not.

Since I'm consuming the API using Akka HTTP then dealing with it using `Sink`-s & `Source`-s given that it supports chunked encoding will be most efficient and seems the most appropriate.

Comment: If I were you I'd rewrite the question exposing the actual API.  As written it is difficult to understand what you want and the overall design is not very intuitive.  Just a friendly suggestion...